# What should our domain be?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/write-and-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name android.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/write-and-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Post your ideas for a dot-com domain name for this website, which captures the spirit and intent of the site, namely:

> {name} is intended for enthusiasts,
> power users, and regular people using
> the Android operating system.

Please follow these guidelines:

- **Check to see if the domain is taken before making the name suggestion**. Taken names, however clever, are not helpful. You can use whois.net to check availability. (Read this [post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) regarding squatted names).
- **Post one domain per answer**. This makes the voting process much easier. If domains are very similar (e.g. "dev" and "devs"), they can be in the same answer.
- **Make sure the domain wasn't already suggested**. To search within this question, use a search query such as: `inquestion:1 "example.com"` replacing `example.com` with the domain to search for.
- **When coming back to this question, make sure to sort the answers "newest first"**, as to not miss new proposals.

Comment: ForceClose.com :P

Comment: @Ivo That's probably one of the things I dislike about the SE model competing with old SE 1.0 sites.

Comment: My first answer was about registered trademarks; I've tried to suggest actual domain-names, but the answer keeps vanishing. Actively deleted, or swallowed by the system?

Comment: Turns out droidoverflow is taken...

Comment: should we avoid the use of registered trademarks? Like, er, Android or Droid?

Comment: @OtherMichael According to the android branding page http://www.android.com/branding.html you can use the word 'Android' and 'Droid' to describe a site, but not as the entire name. Or ' for android' when naming applications.

Comment: Joel says: If the name is registered but is being “squatted,” i.e., there’s something there, it’s just not anything worthwhile, ask the owner if they would sell. If it’s available for a reasonable amount of money, and it’s a great name, and the community loves it, we may even be able to buy it.

Comment: It looks like we don't need to worry about this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/ (At least until they change their minds again.)

Comment: @Al-E: Well, it's not that we don't need to worry about it; it's just that we need to broaden the question:  Forget about domain name... what should our site be called?  --No idea what this means for domain names of SE sites when they come to maturity, though.

Answer (score 6):

AndroidExchange.org

Edit: .com and .net was taken.

Comment: +1 It may be a little vanilla, but it's par for the course, memorable, and it flows off the tongue.

Answer (score 5):

**droid.io** for "Android Input/Output"

"I/O, refers to the communication between an information processing system, and the outside world possibly a human."

This fits in two ways:

1. In a way our community is an android related information processing system based on Inputs (Questions) and Outputs (Answers).
2. Android is itself a system of I/O

I know the .io is a little unconventional but I think the name flows nicely and it's short.

Comment: we could also do some domain hacking with this domain and make it an.droid.io, although I just prefer droid.io.

Answer (score 3):

## RoboticOverlords.[com/org]

Answer (score 2):

AskAnAndroid.com

Comment: I don't like this one anymore.  I'm going with **droid.io** now instead.

Comment: I was going to suggest qnandroid (as in QnA). Same basic idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

RoboticBrainInfo.com

I feel that since androids are a compliment to our brains, in external form, we should graft a site name that compliments it's use.

Comment: Seems slightly long and clumsy. Just **RoboticBrain.com** sounds better to me.

Answer (score 1):

**ElectricSheep.com** (as in "Do Androids Dream of...") is taken, but there's no real content there. I don't know if they'd be amenable to a purchase offer.

Of course, there's Philip K. Dick's heirs who might have something to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

**LittleGreenRobot.com**

Sadly, currently squatted by someone else who appears to want to bring another Android site into the world.

Answer (score 1):

**androiduprising.org**

*available*

maintains the playful tongue-in-cheek feel of stackoverflow, serverfault, etc... all while violating the three laws

.com is regestered (as of 5/10), but is not in use.

Answer (score 1):

**NotificationBar.com**

It got a few up-votes as a comment so I figured I'd post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

## HumanCyborgRelations.[com/org]

(and this is my counterpart, r2d2)

Comment: Ha, if that's really available, I'm tempted to snatch it up myself.

Comment: I believe it is. I still think it's a cool name (even if someone downvoted me)

Comment: It's cool, but I don't think it's a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidMechanics.org

Answer (score 0):

**AlphabeticalDessert.com**

You know, Cupcake, Donut, Eclair, FroYo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb...

Of course, the misspelling AlphabeticalDesert will get snapped up by a spammer in five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

**GullibleStormtrooper.com**

"No, actually, these *are* the droids you're looking for."

A little esoteric. Not to mention the Lucasfilm lawsuit and the negative connection with WWII Germany.

Answer (score 0):

**RoboticBra.in** is available.....

inspired by [RoboticBrainInfo.com](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-should-our-domain-be/51#51)

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't taken by a company in India that makes Robotic Bras.  Maybe there is no such company, if thats the case there definitely should be! Any enterprising VCs out there ready to break into the Indian Cybertronic Lingerie market?

Comment: @Matt - Had a good laugh on that one. Glad I inspired someone. Don't be surprised if while making out, one day, a teenager will find that his girlfriend's bra comes off with just a click of a button.

Comment: Hopefully it'll be multi-touch ;o)

Answer (score -1):

### dragnotificationbar.com

Available

Was trying to think of something unique to android, and take some flavor from the other 2.0 sites and use a verb.  Might be too long though.

Comment: dragnotification is available too

Comment: Or just notificationbar.com even.

Answer (score -1):

What about droidicted.com - Like android adicted as we all are

Answer (score -1):

**positroni.cc**  (double-c because there is no .ic TLD that I can find to register with)

You know. From Asimov.

nevermind.

Comment: I like this name, but not necessarily for the android.SE.

Answer (score -2):

HandyAndy.org

and extra chars added to bypass the filter

Comment: "Handy Andy" was a thoroughly annoying presenter on a UK home makeover show http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Kane No way I can visit a site called that!

Comment: That sounds creepy and NSFW

Comment: Ouch. downvotes. So, this is a WRONG answer, yes?