# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-should-our-domain-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: You mean *an* elevator pitch, no?

Comment: No, I think he mean "write" and "throw the elevator as far as you can". The ElevatorPitch is a sport derived from the CaberToss [please note that in non-Scottish locales the eat() method MUST be overridden to avoid a Haggis dependency; trust me -- the overflow errors on that one are terrible], and it RealBig in StackExchange InnerCircles. At LAN parties it is usually followed by a tag-line, a variation on a conga-line, but with dancer-applied semantics.

Answer (score 7):

Tagline:

These *are* the answers you're looking for.

Comment: I get it, but I'm wondering how many people will. I guess people don't need to get it, it makes sense anyway.

Comment: Nice one, would do well as a motto, but maybe the elevator pitch needs to be *slightly* more descriptive.

Comment: +1 I like this tagline

Comment: After upvoting, I have just one quibble... this tag-line could work for EVERY StackExchange site. How do we make it SPECIFIC ???

Comment: Sure, it could work on the other sites, but it's specifically a play on "Droid", thus making it nano-incrementally that much funnier.

Comment: It needs some hand waving action ;)

Comment: Now I have enough rep to comment! My suggested tweak (that I had to put in it's own answer previously) was: "Android Questions? These are the Answers you are looking for."

Answer (score 2):

Android Answers

Comment: This should be the motto / logo

Answer (score 1):

"Answers for your Android-centric mind."

What do you think?

Comment: You could substitute "mind" with "life" or whatever you feel appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

Al E.'s great idea just needs a little setting up for those that would miss the reference. Something like:

**"Android Questions? These are the Answers you are looking for."**

(No comments under 50 rep is a PITA! Sorry for the additional answer)

Answer (score 0):

*Community-smart answers for your Android superpowers*

WAS: *Community-smart answers for the bundle of powers in your Android*

Comment: The end just sounds really clumsy, could do with being rephrased more along the lines of "Android powered bundle"?

Comment: Good call.  Too many syllables.  While I liked the ending style, it wasn't a common taste.  Adjusted to simplify.

Comment: Much better and have +1'd you to reset you back up to a 0 score (though for the record I wasn't the one that downvoted you).

Comment: I'm still not satisfied with it, but sometimes figuring what's not quite right about an option leads to a better option.  Thx for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Elevator pitch:

Answers to your Android questions, from people who are as passionate about the Android platform as you.